# Any better way to add multiple-column index on a oracle table with hundreds of millions of rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, indexing

I have a table with hundreds of millions of data, and there is no any index on it, now I want to add multiple-column index on it, at the same time, this operation can't affect the online environment, is there any approach to minimize the effect to online environment?

I have tried add index directly :

```
create index give_integral_index on GIVEINFO(ssoid, integral_operate, operatestatus, source_name);
```

and failed.

Comment: execute too long time.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider:

- Adding an `ONLINE` clause - this allows running DML during index creation, but will slow it down
- Adding a `PARALLEL` clause - this may be as much as DOP (degree of parallelism) times faster, but it requires enough resources for all the slave servers to do their work. If you are very limited on resources, don't use this or use a low DOP. It is also mutually exclusive with the `ONLINE` clause
- Adding a `NOLOGGING` clause - this will redo log write, making it run faster, but in case of recovery roll-forward will be impossible

I would try to use `NOLOGGING` + `PARALLEL` with highest possible DOP in a window where there is no DML/DDL activity.